# Identifier Expected when declaring a property with white space for JSDoc typescript

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I am just trying out TypeScript for the first time today on a JS file. I don't want to use the compilation, I just want TS to do some light type checking with JSDoc comment to add type.

I have something like

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} CustomData
 * @property {Array} "My Property"
 */
```

Since the property has a white space in it, I had to put the quotes around it. However, this creates an error `error TS1003: Identifier expected.`

The error seems to be with the use of `"`. How else can I declare a property with whitespace in a JSDoc comment syntax for Typescript?